# IDEA автоимпорт библиотеки Scanner

Tags: intellij-idea

Добрый день помогите нубу. Во всех уроках\видео проскальзывает фраза, что при написании в коде Scanner Среда разработки также подсказывает, что нужно импортировать для того или иного класса - нажмите на покрасневшее имя нового класса правой кнопкой мыши, и выберите "импортировать класс". Так строчка импорта появится сама собой.

Когда в IDEA  я нажимаю на ПКМ, то такой опции нет,  приходится писать вручную. Где я туплю и как это поправить?
СПС[image: введите сюда описание изображения]